# React-hook-form doesn't recognize input value

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, required, onblur, required-field

My react-hook-form doesn't recognize the input value once the user fills the input box.
It keeps returning the 'This field is required' error message with the password field.

Here's my code.

```
function SignIn({ setIsLoginView }: LoginProps) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isDirty, isValid, dirtyFields, touchedFields },
  } = useForm<IFormInput>({
    defaultValues: {
      userId: "",
      userPW: "",
    },
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = (data) => {
    RequestSignin({ username: data.userId, password: data.userPW })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res, data.userId);
        setIsLoginView(!setIsLoginView);
        setStoredToken(res.access_token);
        setAuthenticated();
        dispatch(setLogin(data.userId));
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error);
  };

  return (

        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className="w-1/4"
        >
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label className="block text-sm font-medium mb-1">Username</label>
            <input
              {...register("userId", {
                required: "This field is required",
                maxLength: { value: 20, message: "Maximum length is 20 letters." },
                minLength: { value: 4, message: "Minimum length is 4 letters." },
                // pattern: { value: /^[a-z]+$/, message: "Lower alphabetic letter only." },
              })}
              type="text"
              className="w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200 dark:bg-stone-900"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <span className="text-rose-600 text-xs h-3">{errors?.userId?.message}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label className="block text-sm font-medium mb-1">Password</label>
            <input
              {...register("userPW", {
                required: "This field is required",
                minLength: {
                  value: 4,
                  message: "Please input more than 4 characters.",
                },
              })}
              type="password"
              // required
              className="w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200 dark:bg-stone-900"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              onKeyUp={checkCapsLock}
            />
            {errors.userPW && <span className="text-rose-600 text-xs">{(errors.userPW as FieldError).message}</span>}
            {isCapsLockOn && <span className="text-rose-600 text-xs">Caps Lock is ON</span>}
          </div>
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Sign In"
            className="bg-teal-600 mt-8 text-white font-bold px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-teal-700 m-auto flex w-1/2 justify-center"
          />
        </form>

      <div className="flex justify-center gap-3 mt-10">
        <span className="text-base/10">{optInText[1]}</span>
        <input
          type="submit"
          value={optInText[2]}
          className=" text-teal-500 font-bold hover:text-teal-400 flex"
          onClick={() => setViewSignUp(!viewSignUp)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

I've read the git hub issue: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/3750.
It seems like the questioner had the same issue as mine. I dug it up and tried some codes into mine but it even displayed an error with the 'username' section as well. Guess I didn't thoroughly understand the logic and follow it.

Can someone advise where to begin?

Comment: you dont require, `value` and `onChange` and `useState`. try removing it. also if possible put your code into codesandbox

Comment: As Prashant said, you shouldn't mix react-hook-form with useState. `register` takes care of setting values and listening to changes